# Neo4J Java API:check if a node is reachable from other node

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I am using the Neo4J Java API and I want to check if one node is reachable from the other. The graph factory algorithm does not seem to contain something like that.

Thanks in advance

Altober

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit(from comment): Actually java would be more efficient-use the traversal api, start at one node, traverse till you find the end node and stop. So you wont necessarily end up matching every possible path that exists I suppose*

I can think of doing a shortest path(or another algorithm http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html)  and check the length:

```
 match (node1 {id:"1"}),(node2 {id:"2"}),p=shortestPath((node1)-[*]-(node2))
 return count(rels(p))
```

Or just find the existence of a path of any depth:

```
    match (node1 {id:"1"}),(node2 {id:"2"}),p=(node1)-[*]-(node2) 
    return count(p)
```

Not sure which is less expensive.

Comment: Yes, but the shortest path would require unnecessary computations. In any case the question could be, how to find just one path no matter which one. I do not undertsnd the second one, I can translate it into the Java API eventually. Are ypu looking for every path or just 1?

Comment: Second one tries to match a path of any depth between the two nodes. So it could match many paths if many paths exist. You can still run this as a cypher query via java.

Comment: Actually java would be more efficient-use the traversal api, start at one node, traverse till you find the end node and stop. So you wont necessarily end up matching every possible path that exists I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you are right I will stop the traversal after the first path. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `GraphAlgoFactory` as described in the [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html) and the finder that you get back with `finder.findSinglePath`. I would probably not use dijkstra but shortest path or simple path. See the [GraphAlgoFactory API](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html)